# Calling ToString() on a Reference Type

Tags: c#, object, tostring, reference-type

Given two object arrays I need to compare the differences between the two (when converted to a string). I've reduced the code to the following and the problem still exists:

```
public void Compare(object[] array1, object[] array2) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++) {
        var value1 = GetStringValue(array1[i]);
        var value2 = GetStringValue(array2[i]);
    }
}

public string GetStringValue(object value) {
    return value != null && value.ToString() != string.Empty ?
        value.ToString() : "No Value";
}
```

The code executes fine no matter what object arrays I throw at it. However if one of the items in the array is a reference type then somehow the reference is updated. This causes issues later.

It appears that this happens when calling ToString() against the object reference. I have updated the GetStringValue method to the following (which makes sure the object is either a value type or string) and the problem goes away.

```
public string GetStringValue(object value) {
    return value != null && (value.GetType().IsValueType || value is string)
        && value.ToString() != string.Empty ? value.ToString() : "No Value";
}
```

However this is just a temporary hack as I'd like to be able to override the ToString() method on my reference types and compare them as well.

I'd appreciate it if someone could explain why this is happening and offer a potential solution. Thanks

**Edit**:

To help further explain my application. This piece of code is taken from an NHibernate event listener. I think the problem lies from NHibernate adding it's own wrapper around a class to deal with lazy loading. Here's the error it throws:

> collection [***] was not processed by flush()

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "somehow the reference is updated"? If you could provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem, that would help enormously. (Your code is also more confusing than it needs to be - why call `ToString()` twice? If you want the result to be an empty string if `ToString()` returns an empty string, you don't need to do any replacement...)

Comment: Can you please explain more precisely by what do you mean "reference is updated"?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "the reference is updated"?

Comment: Why do you test for `value.toString() != string.Empty` if you're just going to return the empty string anyway if it fails?

Comment: what do you mean the reference is updated. btw all the array items ARE treated like references, even the value types because of the boxing

Comment: I think if you used this to compare a null value with an empty string, you would get a false match.

Comment: I've updated my question to help further explain my application. I hadn't even considered the lazy loading issue so many i need to create a new instance to compare as suggested by @Ian. I will report back my findings. If you have any others suggetions that would be appreciated. Oh and the actual code doesn't return an empty string (I've ammended it above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like there may well be a side effect going on within the ToString() method for the reference type, which is generally bad practise as this is a method often used by the .NET framework.

For this to be the case the following would have to be true:

- You are using a custom class that yourself or another 3rd Party built.
- Some modification of the object occurs when calling ToString().

To verify this you could just create an instance of the reference type and call ToString() on it. See if the object has changed (GetHashCode() may be one way to determine this). Or you could inspect the code...

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer, since it's asking a clarifying question.

Comment: @Servy: It is an answer given the current information in the post... Often a question can have many answers, I'll change the clarifying question into a way to verify if this is the fault or not.

Comment: If there is not enough information in the question to give a quality answer then you don't answer at all, you either ask questions in comments until they are answered, or you vote to close as "not a real question" if you feel that nobody could answer it with the information provided.  What you don't do is post clarifying questions or low quality answers as answers.

Comment: Do you have the source for these objects you are comparing? If so, you should take the approach of leveraging IEqualityComparer. 

Either way, it's possible that one of the types you are converting has overridden the ToString method and is changing itself in the process. Finally, using Convert.ToString(object) would replace your GetStringValue method much more efficiently.

Finally, it isn't clear what your Compare method is returning since it's return type is void and you don't list the rest of it.

Comment: Thanks I marked this as the answer as not only did it help me recognise the problem, I found a nice solution using your suggestion of creating a new instance. Thanks again.